# QGraphicsItemAnimation pauses after every QTimeLine loop

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

```
QGraphicsBubbleItem::QGraphicsBubbleItem(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem *parentItem)
    : QGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y, width, height, parentItem)
{
    timer = new QTimeLine(3000);
    timer->setFrameRange(0, 100);
    //timer->setLoopCount(3);
    connect(timer, &QTimeLine::finished, timer, &QTimeLine::start);

    animation = new QGraphicsItemAnimation;
    animation->setItem(this);
    animation->setTimeLine(timer);

    animation->setTranslationAt(0, (width/2)*(-1), (height/2)*(-1));
    animation->setRotationAt(0.5, 180);
    animation->setRotationAt(1, 360);

    timer->start();
}
```

There is more to the animation but I've simplified the code to the bit that shows the problem. Item is drawn and is rotating as it should but it stops for a visible moment after every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the QTimeLine uses the curve set to:

```
QTimeLine::EaseInOutCurve
```

Means that the value starts growing slowly, then runs steadily, then grows slowly again. Try [setting the curve shape](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeline.html#curveShape-prop) to Linear:

```
QTimeLine::LinearCurve
```